# Mesibo-How requests are routed when switched from Cloud server to OnPrem

Tags: mesibo

We are evaluating mesibo for InApp messaging within our SaaS application. We would need OnPrem setup to comply to Data compliance requirements.

One clarity we would need on this regard is, when we switch from Cloud to Onprem setup still client side code continues to use https://mesibo.com url. In this case we believe all the traffic gets routed to our OnPrem server via Mesibo server.

Please confirm if this understanding is right? If so would there be any data residing on Mesibo server? This clarity is required for us to respond to our customers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, once you enable On-premise, your client directly connects to your on-premise server. You can verify it using `netstat` utility. mesibo cloud will have no access to your data.

Refer to the following to learn more https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/on-premise/#do-i-need-to-change-or-recompile-my-apps-to-run-with-mesibo-on-premise

> Mesibo APIs support both cloud and on-premise. By default, it connects
> to the cloud. However, if the app is configured to be on-premise, the
> mesibo cloud will refuse to serve and will ask the client to connect
> to an on-premise server, and will disconnect. Then onward, the client
> will directly connect to the on-premise server and then all the
> messages and calls will route to your mesibo on-premise server.